# Can I use an angular service without mentioning it in NgModule's providers?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and following freecodecamp tutorials on youtube. They're 2 years old.

In services tutorial, it is mentioned that we need to mention the Service in `providers` list in root NgModule to make it work. But I haven't mentioned it in providers.

What I observed is that in the tutorial, there is no `providedIn` in the `Injectable()`. But when I created a new service in Angular 10, I got it by default in the `Injectable()`. The service is working without any issues so far.

Are these 2 same?

Can we mention the `providedIn: 'root'` and leave it without mentioning in `providers` list to make it work and viceversa?

Comment: Read this: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: Thanks @R.Richards . That clarified my query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an Angular service singleton to share the same instance in the whole app by doing one of the two possibilities:

1. add it to providers array in your root module (app module)
2. make the service provided in root

   @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
   })

**but the best is to use @Injectable() decorator of the service itself to make it Tree-shakable.**

if now **you can provide the service in your lazy loaded modules level so the service will have a new instance for each module**

or provide the service in the component lever thus your component and its children will have the same instance

```
@Component({
 selector: 'parent',
 template: `...`,
 providers: [ YourService ]
})
```